# How to call squared distance function on two columns in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, partition

**I have a dataframe which looks like this :**

```
+--------------------+--------------------++-------------
|            feature1|            feature2| domain    |
+--------------------+--------------------++-------------
|[2.23668528E8, 1....|[2.23668528E8, 1....| domain1   | 
|[2.23668528E8, 1....|[2.23668528E8, 1....| domain2   |
|[2.23668528E8, 1....|[2.23668528E8, 1....| domain1   |
|[2.23668528E8, 1....|[2.23668528E8, 1....| domain2   |
|[2.23668528E8, 1....|[2.23668528E8, 1....| domain1   |
```

**The schema of the dataframe is this :**

```
|-- domain: string (nullable = true)
|-- feature1: vector (nullable = true)
|-- feature2: vector (nullable = true)
```

**The columns feature1 and feature2 are of type Vector.Dense. I want to calculate the squared distance. I tried this way :**

```
all_pairs_df.withColumn(
    "distance",
    Vectors.squared_distance(all_pairs_df.feature2, all_pairs_df.feature1)
).show()
```

But I am getting the error, any idea how to achieve this in pyspark without using a udf that eventually calls BatchEvalPython?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @AILearning  `TypeError: Cannot convert type <class 'pyspark.sql.column.Column'> into Vector` this is error I am getting, I know why this error is coming but don't know the workaround.

Comment: why not use an udf?

Comment: @mtoto I wanted to reduce serialization and deserialization needed to execute python's udf since the data has million of records.